# Thunderbird mail "Deleted" folder

Tags: thunderbird

My "Deleted" file folder disappeared in my Thunderbird Email, so I created a new "Deleted" folder but any deleted Emails don't show there.  Think this just happened a day ago with the latest upgrade from Ubuntu??
What now?
Gary

Answer (score 0):

Check you "Account settings" (Menu, Preferences - Account Settings). In the left pane, select "Server Settings" under the account where you have the issue. Check the settings under "When I delete a message". If you check the option ""Move it to this folder: " and then select the "Deleted" folder that you (re-)created), then, after clicking OK in the dialog, it will again function as a special "Deleted" folder.